# Modifying url with php

Tags: php, url

I am sorry for bad english but I will do my best to explain what I actually want.

Lets consider that I have a news in my database that has

```
id = 3 
name = one example string
```

I am finding a solution to change a link like:

```
www.example.com/news.php?id=3
```

into something like this:

```
www.example.com/news/one-example-string
```

or

```
www.example.com/one-example-string
```

Comment: Your English is quite perfect, actually ;-)

Comment: What you ask is usually implemented not in php but on the level of the http server using "request rewriting". That works on _incoming_ requests, analyzes them by means of string operations and translates the requests back to php scripts internally which are provided with the request arguments as required. You will find _tons_ of examples for that when searching for the terms I mentioned.

Comment: @arkascha thank you :)

Comment: However you definitely should rethink your final URL scheme. For technical reasons it should be something like `www.example.com/news/3/one-example-string`, since you do not want to mess around with complex string pattern comparisons but use the crunchy numerical ID instead. That's what it is for in the end...

Comment: @arkascha so I need to edit ".htacces" file on my website?

Comment: You want to implement internal rewriting rules. Sounds like you are using an apache http server if you mention a file named `.htaccess`. Such a dynamic configuration file is an option, yes. Much better is to place such rules inside the actual http servers (virtual) host configuration. Dynamic configuration files really slow down the server and cause a lot of trouble, they are only provided as a last option for those without any access to the actual server configuration (read: really cheap hosting service provider).